# Angular toggle class on a different template

Tags: angularjs

In my `header.html` page I have this button:

```
<button class="tabs-menu-btn" ng-click="toggle = !toggle" ng-class="{'open' : toggle}">
    <div></div>
</button>
```

And on `wrapper.html` I have this div:

```
<div class="tabs-toolbar" ng-class="{'open' : toggle}">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab">
            <a ng-click="toggle = !toggle" ui-sref-active="selected" ui-sref="flows"><span>Flows</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So when the button is clicked I want to toggle the 'open' class on the button and div - but currently it only works on the button, if i move the 'tabs-toolbar' onto the same html page it works. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: They probably don't share the same scope object, as you state that they are in different templates/pages. A quick workaround is to use `$root.toggle` everywhere, but you probably might want to rethink your architecture

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Which part is not clear @Sudharsan S  ??

Comment: As @devqon said they probably not share the same scope, [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/s6COWvCEGwo3WpKpuNev?p=preview) is an example on how you can use the rootScope

Answer (score 0):

header and wrapper are part of two different scope. So when you click toggle its is changing only the  $scope.header.toggle = false 
sample Example:

```
$scope.header.toggle = true
$scope.wrapper.toggle = false // its not getting reflected because, this scope will not get effected with the action
```

Solution 
make both variable as part of same controller or trigger a function which changes both scope